# Google Play Game Services with libGDX

Tags: libgdx, google-play-games

I have tried to integrate Google Play Game Services with my libGDX project.

I have used this code in MainGame class:

```
public static PlayServices playServices;

public MainGame(PlayServices playServices)
{
    this.playServices = playServices;
}
```

I put this code in MainMenu class, where I would like to show up login Google's login form after some user interactions.

```
public static MainGame game;

public MainMenu(MainGame game)
{
    this.game = game;
}
```

When I tried to run app, got following error:

> Error:(77, 68) error: constructor MainMenu in class MainMenu cannot be
>   applied to given types; required: MainGame found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: At least give a +1 ?

Comment: @ossobuko : Certainly! Can you maybe help a bit again. I have checked mentioned problems, but all of it is correct. Tutorial doesn't say to create the class, only to give some extra functions to it.
I can also sign this as solved! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to send an instance of PlayServices to your core module from Android module. If this is not the case, please correct me and provide more code because I cannot make anything else out of the information you supplied.

You need to use an interface.

In your core module create an interface. Which has necessary functions like connectToGooglePlayServices(), unlockAchivement() etc. All the things that is exclusive to Android.

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements ThatInterfaceClass {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(this), config);
    }
    @Override
    public void connectToGooglePlayServices() {
        //connect to play services here
    }

    @Override
    public void unlockAchivement() {
        // unlock achivement etc.
    }

}
```

Important part here is giving this as a parameter to the `MyGdxGame` class constructor, and implementing `ThatInterfaceClass`.

After this put a parameter in your MyGdxGame class' constructor.

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    public void MyGdxGame (ThatInterfaceClass interface) {
        this.interface = interface;
    }

    // create etc... Other functions....
}
```

Now in order to connect to the google play services or unlock an achivement just call `interface.connectToGooglePlayServices()`

Here is a link which explains this better.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

**EDIT:** It seems the problem is in the code you didn't supply here. Look at this example of how you should creat
e a instance of MainMenu class.

```
MainGame mainGame = new MainGame(playServices);
MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu(mainGame);
```

I believe you are constructing MainMenu class like this:

```
MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
```

As long as you have this constructor:

```
public MainGame(PlayServices playServices)
{
    this.playServices = playServices;
}
```

You cannot use constructor without PlayServices parameter. But you could erase your contructor or remove the PlayServices parameter and use it like this:

```
MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
mainMenu.setPlayServices(playServices);
```

Here is another question like yours:

["Actual or formal argument lists differs in length"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749409/actual-or-formal-argument-lists-differs-in-length)

**EDIT 2:** Is your MainMenu class in the **android module** of the **core module**? If it is not in **android module** you cannot use PlayServices class (also cannot have an instance). Also don't look for a workaround just use an interface to initiate the connection. As I said in the initial answer.

**EDIT 3: FINAL:** It could have been easier for both of us if you have told about the tutorial before. 
The image you sent in the comments says playServices cannot be resolved:

1. Make sure you didn't type anything wrong.
2. Make sure the PlayServices interface is in the core module.
3. Read the tutorial again. Make sure you added libraries, dependencies etc. correctly.
4. The tutorial tells you to create AndroidLauncher activity. But libGdx creates it by default.

Apart from this I cannot help you further, without sitting on your chair. For your next questions, please supply more information. A lot more.

Comment: Yes, you are right!
I have already implemented interface(this is `PlayServices`) and all the necessary functions. My menu is similar to yours, but it gives error, when I try to call `MainMenu` from another classes.

Comment: I have tried on another class correct instance of `MainMenu` class in another class. It gives this error in this other class: http://prntscr.com/9yn8lg

Comment: `MainMenu` is in core project, but `PlayServices` interface is also in core project. This approach is based on this tutorial: https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/how-to-setup-google-play-game-services-in-libgdx-using-android-studio/