# Error: exception is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have a problem with a try-catch code. The excercise wants me to modify the code:

[image: This, to the one in the other picture]

It gives me this error: [image: And in the book where I'm learning there's no solution to the actual excercise]

I know it might be in Spanish but I think that with seeing the error you can help me and tell me what's wrong with it.

Comment: You really should post the code here, as it may otherwise be impossible to see it. Regardless, it's because you're calling a method, and not using the correct number of parametres in the call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749409/actual-or-formal-argument-lists-differs-in-length

Comment: Hum, there's a title / error mismatch, please cleanup your question

Comment: @AntonH Please check the pictures / code. Don't trust the question titles.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm at work and can't see the pictures, which is why I commented first to put the code. The second remark was based on the then-title.

Comment: The error you show in the post body is "Exception never thrown in the body", not "...lists differ in length"

Comment: @AntonH Okay, but my statement about not trusting still stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `remove`, or those other methods `throw` a `new NoCoincideContactoException`.

Currently, the error is saying that the try is pointless because nothing is thrown.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, you mean to put it in the method? "public void eliminarContacto(String clave) throws NoCoincideContactoException"  like that?

Comment: Nope. I said what I meant already. The `try` is pointless. That is what the error says. You are catching nothing unless **`remove`** throws something