# No arguments found, javafx.stage.Stage required

Tags: java

I have tried repeatedly to make this work, google, looking through guides, changing the code etc etc, this is the most stable code I see and I am unsure how to fix it. The code can be shown.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jFyu.png)

The error is displayed as such:
method btnPlay_Video in class SpotifyBasicGUI cannot be applied to given types;
required: javafx.stage.Stage
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: The method you are trying to call needs a parameter that you pass it of type javafx.stage.Stage. You can't call that method without any arguments.

Comment: Do these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749409/actual-or-formal-argument-lists-differs-in-length and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813484/java-error-actual-and-formal-argument-lists-differ-in-length

Comment: Hi, please follow these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. More specifically, do not post images of code