# java: method nextLong in class java.util.Random cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, random

Here's the simple method that gave me the error:

```java
protected static long random(long a, long b) {
    //Random random = new Random();
    return a + new Random().nextLong(b - a);
}
```

And here are the errors from the terminal:

```
java: method nextLong in class java.util.Random cannot be applied to given types;

  required: no arguments

  found:    long

  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: Instead of writing your own method to generate a random number within the bounds provided, `Random` has a method `nextLong(long origin, long bound)`

Comment: Also see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17749409/21252090) helps

Comment: @GrindingForReputation no, Random doesn't has that method.

Comment: @aled on JDK 21 at least, `java.util.random.RandomGenerator.nextLong(long origin, long bound)` exists, and it can be used through `new Random().nextLong(a, b)` as `Random` implements `RandomGenerator`

Comment: The method `nextLong(long origin, long bound)` does indeed exist. It was introduced in Java 17. If you're using an old version of Java, you should consider upgrading, preferably to 21 or 22.

Comment: Another thing to note, the reason your getting this error is that the `Random` class only has a `nextLong()` method. Should be the reason your getting the error. Update your Java version

Comment: @k314159 not everyone has the convenience to upgrade, usually due to a PM that doesn't understand Java. Either way, there's `Random#nextLong()` for you since Java 8. **But** there's also `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(origin, bound);` available to you since Java 8 as well, and no more crap from `new Random()` being done all the time.

Comment: @GrindingForReputation, after changing to  `return new Random().nextLong(a, b);` 
java: method nextLong in class java.util.Random cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found:    long,long
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length**

Comment: @sctts-lol its a difference in the version you use. You can use Rogue's answer to help

Comment: The comments and answer address the question of "how do you generate a long in a given range", but don't explain OP's errors: your version of Java doesn't have a method `Random.nextLong` which takes a single long parameter; you need to refer to the API docs to find out what methods are available.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ive answered the question. *Another thing to note, the reason your getting this error is that the Random class only has a nextLong() method*

Comment: Don't do `new Random()`, if this is called in a tight loop, you might get the exact same value repeatedly. Use `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel no, the default constructor creates a unique seed. See the Javadoc and implementation for details.

Comment: @k314159 Thanks for pointing that out. Now I'm wondering if it used to be different in the past, or if I'm misremembering such behaviour from a different language and thinking it was Java.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you're not _completely_ misremembering: older versions of Java (like 1.2) used to seed it with `System.currentTimeMillis()` which obviously could well be the same seed if run in a loop 1000 times. Now (since at least 1.7) it uses a "seed uniquifier" in addition to `nanotime`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ThreadLocalRandom`, there's no need for your helper method:

```
long origin = 0;
long bound = 1000;
//A random long in the range [0, 1000)
long rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(origin, bound);
```

This is available in Java 7 and later. Earlier on, `Random` did not have some of the helper methods provided through `RandomGenerator` (in Java 17), so you only have the `Random#nextLong()` method (with *no* arguments). This number had to be manually modulo'd, which can lead to distribution issues down the line. It's much better to use `ThreadLocalRandom` here in this case, as it will be uniformly distributed.

Comment: The reason I am implementing a random method cause I have to try out different primality test(e.g Rabin-Miller), hence I don't want to fixated a specific bounding. Thanks @Rogue

Comment: @sctts-lol nothing preventing you from passing new bounds to `ThreadLocalRandom`, you would use it exactly the same way you would've used your custom `#random` method.